# atmosphere framework independent of browsers

Tags: java, atmosphere

I need to use atmosphere framework in my application. What i need is to load a database values on `onOpen()` function. Then return particular rows of the database on `onMessage()` function according to the client inputs. So edited the [chat](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-samples/tree/master/samples/chat) example. In browser `localhost:8080` its working perfectly. But when i trying to access  the server through new browser , i can see that the server holds the old values that i was used in the previous browser. How can i use the application without this problem? Thanks

Comment: Which part you've edited? Can you show the code?